# Second order non-linear equation with non linear first derivative

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am having trouble figuring out a method for finding a solution to

$$r + \left(\frac{2}{r}\right)\left(r^{'}\right)^2-r^{''}=0$$

I have tried substitution of  $\ \ w = r^{'}$  to obtain

$$r + \left(\frac{2}{r}\right)w^{2} = \frac{dw}{dr}w$$

But then I am not sure how to proceed from there.

Any suggestions are welcome.  Thanks

Comment: By the way, how did you obtain that $r''=\frac{dw}{dr}w$? It looks suspicious. Do you consider $w$ as a function of $r$? What is $r$ a function of?

Comment: r being a function of theta, I expanded the chain rule on it.   $\frac{dw}{d\theta} = \frac{dw}{dr} \frac{dr}{d\theta}$.  Then since $\frac{dr}{d\theta} = w$  the substitution was made

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if we let $u(t)=1/r(t)$? Then
$$
r'=-\frac{1}{u^2}u'\quad \text{and}\quad r''=\frac{2}{u^3}(u')^2-\frac{1}{u^2}u''
$$
Hence,
$$
\begin{aligned}
r+\frac{2}{r}(r')^2-r''&=\frac{1}{u}+2u\Bigl(-\frac{1}{u^2}u'\Bigr)^2-\frac{2}{u^3}(u')^2+\frac{1}{u^2}u''\\
&=\frac{u+u''}{u^2}.
\end{aligned}
$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you very much.  I will work through with this

Comment: This worked out very well.  Thank you very much

Comment: @54stickers if you are happy with this answer you should accept this answer :).

Answer (score 1):

A side note - you were so close following your approach.
$$
r +\frac{2}{r}w^2 = w'w = \frac{1}{2}\dfrac{d}{dr}w^2
$$
sitting $w^2 = u$ then you get
$$
\frac{1}{2}u' -\frac{2}{r}u = r
$$